# Constant dhcpcd errors: eth0: authentication failed from IP address: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, wifi, bluetooth, ethernet, dhcp

My syslog is full of these errors:

```
Feb 14 13:24:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[564]: eth0: authentication failed from aa11::1111:aaaa:aa11:a1a1: No such file or directory
Feb 14 13:25:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[564]: eth0: authentication failed from aa11::1111:aaaa:aa11:a1a1: No such file or directory
Feb 14 13:28:03 raspberrypi dhcpcd[564]: eth0: authentication failed from aa11::1111:aaaa:aa11:a1a1: No such file or directory
```

I munged the IP address because I don't know if it's sensitive info or not. I don't recognize it and neither do any of the DNS lookups and whois queries I've tried.

This line is repeated at irregular intervals - sometimes one or two minutes between, sometimes only a few seconds - starting shortly after boot. There are a few other errors that happen prior to this but I'm not sure if they're relevant:

```
Feb 14 12:35:13 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Feb 14 12:35:13 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt failed with error -2
Feb 14 12:35:13 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Feb 14 12:35:13 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Jan  4 2021 19:56:29 version 7.45.229 (617f1f5 CY) FWID 01-2dbd9d2e
Feb 14 12:35:18 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
Feb 14 12:35:25 raspberrypi kernel: ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time_ms instead
Feb 14 12:35:25 raspberrypi bluetoothd[496]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 14 12:35:25 raspberrypi bluetoothd[496]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 14 12:35:26 raspberrypi bluetoothd[496]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
```

Everything seems to be working as far as I can tell. I'm using a wired ethernet connection, so if these errors are related to bluetooth or wifi I guess I wouldn't notice.

Comment: It is trying to contact an non existent IPv6 address you can tell by the `::` in the address, nothing to worry about if you do not have such an address, most do not at this time it is still an IPv4 world for the vast majority of us. If it was your wireless it would say `wlan0` in the error, no clue what a bluetooth network link is shown as.

Comment: Is there anything that doesn't work? If you waste time looking at log files you will find lots of nonexistent "errors"

Comment: All of my pi's have the same "error" ... except one ... which is odd ... in my case the ipv6 address is `fe80:.... etc` which is the link-local address of my dhcp server - not sure what's different about that one pi! happens to be my "main" pi, so least amount of tinkering with that

Answer (score 0):

> There are a few other errors that happen prior to this but I'm not sure if they're relevant

They're actually an hour previous (dunno if you noticed this).

The bit after the hostname, if it isn't `kernel`, is a process name and PID (eg. `bluetoothd[496]`.  The kernel stuff there isn't an error *except for* the note about `dhcpcd` (which is something that is spit out regarding `dhcpcd` for a while now, I presume they are aware, and it isn't an operational problem as far as I know).  The bluetoothctl stuff isn't relevant.

The `dhcpcd` "authentication failed from" stuff is I think bogus/chimeric -- it's because of some IPv6 confusion (possibly related to the ICMPv6 deprecated call).  Anyway, I've seen it and never felt any grief.

Comment: Good catch. The dhcpcd errors actually start right after the other errors. I just copied them from somewhere in the middle.